# Grid view inside HorizontalScrolView

Tags: android

May i know how to put a `GridView` in `HorizontalScrollView`.
My xml code is given below but it is not wroking.

```
<HorizontalScrollView android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="500dp" android:layout_height="500dp">
    <GridView android:layout_width="500dp" android:layout_height="400dp" 
        android:id="@+id/grid" android:columnWidth="65dp" android:padding="5dp" 
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
        android:numColumns="4"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Do you want both horizontal and vertical scroll view  for grid view or just horizontal

Comment: Either I am blind or you have forgot to post your xml code here

Comment: Please define "not working". What happens? What should happen? Any exceptions?

Comment: You cannot really put a GridView inside a ScrollView - nor is there really any need to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this property for the xml of gridView :

```
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
```

and there is no need to put the gridView in a HorizontalScrollVoew as the gridView itself has as the scrolling property.

Comment: hello i am trying to put this property but its no result

Comment: Does not work. GridView does not scroll horizontally. It must be in a HorizontalScrollView

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Only working solution i found is @Till's one.

Answer (score 7):

My solution is:in xml file,put the GridView into a LinearLayout,then put the LinearLayout into the HorizontalScrollView.finally set the LinearLayout's width.

```
LayoutParams linearParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)gridview.getLayoutParams();
        linearParams.width=100*al.size();
        gridview.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
        gridview_type1.setColumnWidth(100);
```

let HorizontalScrollView know the LinearLayout'width,so the HorizontalScrollView can start and stop to Scroll. And don't forget android:orientation="horizontal" in LinearLayout.

Comment: This works. Only solution I found that allows for both vertical and horizontal scrolling of gridview.

Comment: A solution for horizontal scrolling of gridview that works without needing to make a whole new class or using a library. Thank you very much!

Comment: What is that al.size()?